# Spring mvc HandlerMapping VS HandlerAdapter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have been reading Spring MVC `HandlerMapping` and `HandlerAdapter` but I am getting confused between this two concepts.I can understand that `HandlerMapping` is used to map incoming HTTP request to controller but `what is the use of HandlerAdapter?`
`why do we use it?`
`what is the exact difference between these two with example?`
 Please help me on this.Thanks !!

Answer (score 16):

Since introduction of RequestMappingHandlerMapping and RequestMappingHandlerAdapter in Spring 3.1 the distinction is even simpler: 
RequestMappingHandlerMapping finds the appropriate handler method for the given request. RequestMappingHandlerAdapter executes this method, providing it with all the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The **HandlerMapping** is used to Maps a request to Handlers i.e. Controllers. For example: DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping, SimpleUrlHandlerMapping, BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping. DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.

`<mvc:annotation-driven />` declares explicit support for annotation-driven MVC controllers. The tag configures two beans (Mapping and Adapter) `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` and `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` so that you do not need to declare them in context config file.

The **HandlerAdapter** is basically an interface which facilitates the handling of HTTP requests in a very flexible manner in Spring MVC. The DispatcherServlet  doesn’t invoke the method directly – it basically serves as a bridge between itself and the handler objects, leading to a loosely coupling design.

```
public interface HandlerAdapter {
    //check if a particular handler instance is supported or not. 
    boolean supports(Object handler);

   //used to handle a particular HTTP request and returns ModelAndView object to DispatcherServlet
    ModelAndView handle(
      HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response, 
      Object handler) throws Exception;

    long getLastModified(HttpServletRequest request, Object handler);
}
```

**Types of HandlerAdapter :**
[image]

**AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter** :  which executes methods annotated with `@RequestMapping`. AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter was deprecated and replace by **RequestMappingHandlerAdapter** from Spring 3.1+.

SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter: This is the default handler adapter registered by Spring MVC. It deals with classes implementing Controller interface and is used to forward a request to a controller object.

If a web application uses only controllers then we don’t need to configure any HandlerAdapter as the framework uses this class as the default adapter for handling a request.

Let’s define a simple controller class, using the older style of controller (implementing the Controller interface):

```
public class SimpleController implements Controller {
    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(
      HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("Greeting");
        model.addObject("message", "Dinesh Madhwal");
        return model;
    }
}
```

Similar XML configuration:

```
<beans ...>
    <bean name="/greeting.html"
      class="com.baeldung.spring.controller.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapterExample"/>
    <bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

[for more](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handler-adapters)